# Codeigniter 3 controller requested twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I used codeigniter 3 to make the webservices for an application. At random the result is a fatal error:

```
Severity: Core Warning --> Module 'tidy' already loaded Unknown 0
```

From what i see in the log it looks that the request is made twice.

```
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> START API CALL
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config file loaded: /application/config/site.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: ai_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: security_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/admin_lang.php
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config file loaded: /application/config/ion_auth.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Email Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/ion_auth_lang.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: cookie_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: date_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/form_validation_lang.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Total execution time: 0.0221
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> END API
ERROR - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Severity: Core Warning --> Module 'tidy' already loaded Unknown 0
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> START API CALL
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config file loaded: /application/config/site.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: ai_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: security_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/admin_lang.php
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Config file loaded: /application/config/ion_auth.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Email Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/ion_auth_lang.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: cookie_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Helper loaded: date_helper
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Language file loaded: language/english/form_validation_lang.php
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> Total execution time: 0.0135
DEBUG - 2015-09-17 15:20:25 --> END API
```

START API CALL is showing in the construct function of the controller

END API is showing in the _return_output function

```
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
$this->output->set_status_header(200);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($content));
$this->output->_display();
log_message('debug', 'END API');
exit();
```

Any idea how to prevent the controller to be requested twice?

Thanks

Edit

Api calls:

```
http://domain.dev/api/v1/init
http://domain.dev/api/v1/get_articles
```

Routes:

```
$route['api/v1/(:any)'] = '/api/api/$1';
```

Comment: Could you please show how you call this API?

Comment: and how are those calls executed in your tests? click on a link? triggered by an action in JS? URL in Browser?

Comment: test with `wget -O- http://domain.dev/api/v1/init`

Comment: post requests to those urls from ios or android application